# Where can I ask about the RJ45 specification?

Tags: discussion, questions, site-recommendation, scope

Where can I ask the following?

---

The Cisco [Field Notice: FN - 63697](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/field-notices/636/fn63697.html) was first released on 11-Nov-13, advising customers that RJ45 boots "Might Push the Mode Button and Cause an Unexpected Reset on [some] Switches". This caused a recall of those devices, costing Cisco many monies.

[image: Cisco Switch Mode button being pressed by RJ45 boot]

Consequentially, the Internet likes to ridicule the designer of this particular device for missing this, however, is it really their fault? Is the boot actually part of the RJ45 design specification, or is it a non-standard addition?

- If the RJ45 boot is not included in the RJ45 spec, then it would be a
  non-standard addition. As such, the Cisco design team should be
  forgiven as they would have been working to the official
  specification.
- If, however, the RJ45 boot *is* included in the official RJ45 spec,
  then indeed, the Cisco design team should have known better.

I have tried to find a definitive answer but cannot find one. I would be most grateful for your help!

Comment: Side note - yes, this does feel like grounds for an "Um, Actually" question. https://www.youtube.com/c/umactually

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It would appear the closest fit would be [Network Engineering](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) under the **physical infrastructure** (e.g. standard color coding of cables, types of fiber, etc.) criteria.

There are a few [questions on RJ45 now](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/search?q=Rj45).

I’d recommend rewording the question into whether or not the boot is in the specifications and tone down the reference to Cisco failing to account for the boot.

Comment: Thanks. I guess that, while it was the inspiration for the question, the Cisco part is not necessarily pivotal to the question itself.

Comment: I do think that a *brief* mention of the boot fiasco (or is it ciscasco?) would provide context to the question and explain *why* the question is worth considering.

Comment: Asked on [NE](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/80730/39690) as suggested.

Answer (score 2):

The help for our Network Engineering site clearly says:

> "Note: All questions about RESIDENTIAL/HOME networking and CONSUMER-grade equipment, are explicitly OFF-topic.".

I think they would prefer that your question require a professional setting, rather than be of a nature where the device *could* be used at home; even if it's a small business.

While your question might technically be on-topic it could receive a cold reception.

With [26 questions](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/rj45) your question is likely to be more warmly welcomed on our Server Fault site.

Comment: If you use Cisco kit in your home, you are a braver soul than I!